# Samsung DVD HDD Recorder HR 775, Copy from hardrive to external source

Tags: hard-drive, usb

Hi I own the Samsung HR775 and i'm trying to copy files from  it's hardrive to an external computer but there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this, It has a USB port but that seems to be more for importing from cameras and USB sticks and there's no mention of exporting files from the hardrive. I'm not sure if it's capably of this function.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though I know of no way to get USB A/V output, you might be able to use the [HDMI *output* from the DVD recorder to the HDMI port or USB port on a PC](https://makesfit.com/how-to-change-hdmi-output-to-input-on-laptop/). "There are very few high-end laptops that support HDMI input," but you can use an HDMI to USB adapter, such as [Assletes Video Capture Cards, 4K HDMI to USB 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B091NWB4RJ), [HDMI Capture Dongle Adapter Card, HDMI to USB 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077HGPYM1), or [HDMI Video Capture Card,HDMI to USB 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08L4QYYFK).

Those I've found online vary from US$20 to over $400, and I have not tried any, so check reviews and consult others who've use one before buying.